# Make specific item in NestedScrollView not scroll

Tags: java, android

When I added **floatingactionbutton** in **NestedScroll** the floatingbutton scroll with the whole screen so I want it not scrolling.

I tried to add **RelativeLayout** as a parent and added **floating** inside it and it is ok not scrolling, but the problem is that I use this **floating** to scroll to top when the user **scroll RecyclerView**, because the **RecyclerView** in another group **"RelativeLayout"** it doesn't do the work, so how can I make the **floatingbutton** not scroll and do the job?!

### Her's my code for full explanations.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:background="@color/colorBackground"
android:fadeScrollbars="false"
android:fastScrollEnabled="false"
android:fillViewport="true"
android:overScrollMode="never"
android:scrollbars="none"
tools:context=".Fragment.ImagesFragmentProject.HomeImagesFragment">

<!-- "descendantFocusability" to make the recyclerView not scrolls to the top itself -->
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/colorBackground"
    android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants">

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab_wallpaper"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_gravity="top|center"
        android:layout_margin="20dp"
        android:src="@drawable/up_arrow"
        android:visibility="gone"
        app:backgroundTint="#6D353232" />

    <!-- chooses images text -->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/choose_text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="3dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:text="مميز"
        android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <!--@scrollbars to remove the line of scroll -->
    <!--@fillViewport vit the child view to all the screen -->

    <!-- editor's chooses text -->

    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView_image"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/choose_text"
        android:layout_marginTop="-7dp"
        android:fadeScrollbars="false"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:scrollbars="none">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button6_morining"
                android:layout_width="138dp"
                android:layout_height="84dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
                android:background="@drawable/morning_image"
                android:paddingLeft="26dp"
                android:paddingTop="56dp"
                android:text="الصباح والمساء"
                android:textColor="#fff"
                android:textSize="18sp" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button2_saleheen"
                android:layout_width="138dp"
                android:layout_height="84dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
                android:background="@drawable/aqwal_image"
                android:paddingLeft="30dp"
                android:paddingTop="56dp"
                android:text="أقوال الصالحين"
                android:textColor="#fff"
                android:textSize="16sp" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button6_others"
                android:layout_width="138dp"
                android:layout_height="84dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
                android:background="@drawable/more_image"
                android:paddingLeft="50dp"
                android:paddingTop="56dp"
                android:text="صور منوعة"
                android:textColor="#fff"
                android:textSize="18sp" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button_ma3alem_islamic"
                android:layout_width="138dp"
                android:layout_height="84dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
                android:background="@drawable/aqsa_image"
                android:paddingLeft="44dp"
                android:paddingTop="56dp"
                android:text="المسجد الأقصى"
                android:textColor="#fff"
                android:textSize="16sp" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </HorizontalScrollView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/choose_text2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/scrollView_image"
        android:paddingTop="8dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:paddingBottom="4dp"
        android:text="رآئج"
        android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerview_image_choose"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/choose_text2"
        android:background="@color/colorBackground"
        android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

</androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>

**The code that makes scrolls "Java" when click on floatingbuton**

```
        // add floating button to go up when click on it
    final FloatingActionButton fab2 = rootView.findViewById(R.id.fab_wallpaper);
    fab2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            recyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(20);
        }
    });

    // floating button Visibility and set time for that
    recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrolled(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {

            if (dy > 0) { // scrolling down
                new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        fab2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }
                }, 2000); // delay of 2 seconds before hiding the fab

            } else if (dy < 0) { // scrolling up

                fab2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onScrollStateChanged(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
            if (newState == RecyclerView.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE) { // No scrolling
                new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        fab2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }
                }, 2000); // delay of 2 seconds before hiding the fab
            }

        }
    });
```

Comment: Hello, what does u mean not do the job!

Comment: Because the RecyclerView in another group and the floating in another one, it doesn't do scroll to top when clicking on floating

Answer (score 0):

because your floating action button is in nestedscrollview so it will move when you scroll.
Just move your button out side nestedscrollview. Like this

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        
<!--        put your scroll content here-->
    </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Thank you Nguyen for your answer, I have mentioned above that I have already done this command, but the problem is that the FloatingButton function does not happen. Meaning when the user clicks on the FloatingButton it does not scroll up.